# How do you create a chat room from comments?

Tags: support, chat

I've seen chat-rooms created from over-extended comment exchanges, copying the accumulated commentary into the room. How is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a button which automatically appears on particularly long comment threads. Unfortunately there is [currently no other way access this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106467/238438). I have not tried the javascript snippet posted in the answer there, but I'd be happy to give it a go if you have a particular conversation in mind.

Comment: I must have been particularly inept at finding search-terms for existing questions on this issue. [Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120915/edge-angle-dependent-material-apply/120987?noredirect=1#comment214408_120987) is the thread I think would be better in chat. (I've seen shorter exchanges moved, but I've had no offer from the bot.)